# createFileAtPath, in swift

Tags: swift

I want to download files from url ( which does not have direct url ) and save file in local directory with different name and extension.

For eg, a.jpg

But when the files save, the files damaged and can't open anymore.

Can anyone help me, plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just rename an extension. You have to convert it.

Here is a way to do it:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
NSData *jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage);
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank for your answer Horray.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!! If you like the answer, please accept it. Thanks

Comment: My download file type can be everything. Not only image data. So what should I do?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert it, or how to detect which format it's in?

Comment: I know which format it's in. But whenever I save, I can't open it anymore.
The file is broken.

Comment: I can't go through all the formats and explain how to convert them. I'd suggest searching online for every format you wanna convert. ex. "Convert excel to .pdf in ios.